# Passing a struct to a process through shared memory in C

Tags: c, struct, shared

For a uni assignment I am trying to create a structure in shared memory, write some data in it, and then let the child read it. I've come up with something but, since I am new to C, I am getting some errors that I can't quite understand, here is the code:

```
typedef struct file
{
    int pid;
    char tipo[2];
    char nome[20];
    unsigned long genoma;
    char shmPtr[];
} file_entry;

int main (void)
{

int shmid;
int n;
file_entry *entries;

if (fork() == 0) {
    if ((shmid = shmget(20441, sizeof(file_entry) + 256, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) {
        printf("shmget");
        exit(2);
    }

    entries = (file_entry*) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    if (entries->shmPtr == (char *) -1) {
        printf("problem2");
        exit(2);
    }

    printf("\nChild Reading ....\n\n");
    printf("%c\n", entries->shmPtr[0]);
    printf("%c\n", entries->shmPtr[1]);
    printf("%c\n", entries->shmPtr[2]);
    printf("%c\n", entries->shmPtr[3]);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("\nDone\n\n");
} else {
    if ((shmid = shmget(20441, sizeof(file_entry) + 256, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) {
        printf("problem3");
        exit(2);
    }

    entries = (file_entry *) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    if (entries->shmPtr == (char *) -1) {
        printf("problem4");
        exit(2);
    }
    printf("done attachment");

    int pidD = 1234;
    char tipoD[2] = "A";
    char nomeD[20] = "NOMEINDIVIDUO";
    unsigned long genomaD = 10000;


    entries->shmPtr[0]= pidD;
    entries->shmPtr[1]=tipoD;
    entries->shmPtr[2]=nomeD;
    entries->shmPtr[3]= genomaD;


    wait(NULL);
    shmdt(&shmid);
}
exit(0);
```

}

The errors I'm getting are those:

```
shared memory example 2.c:74:27: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [2]' [-Wint-conversion]
    entries->shmPtr[1]=tipoD;
                      ^~~~~~
shared memory example 2.c:75:27: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [20]' [-Wint-conversion]
    entries->shmPtr[2]=nomeD;
```

I tried to declare the dimension of the variables in the struct and the variables on the father to be the same thinking that it would help, but it didn't. Does anyone know how to solve this? If you also have some example code that would be appreciated.

Comment: why you use shmPtr ?

Comment: Isn't that a good way to access the elements inside of the struct, as an array?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line: `entries->shmPtr[1]=tipoD;`?

Comment: I am trying to assign the value of tipoD to the struct so that I can send it to the child

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: How can you get it to work? I keep trying but it always catches on the problem3 error when I run it, do you compile it in a specific way?

Comment: No i simply compiled it with gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this test application and it works:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct file
{
    int pid;
    char tipo[2];
    char nome[20];
    unsigned long genoma;
} file_entry;

int main (void)
{

    int shmid;
    int n;
    file_entry *entries;

    if (fork() == 0) {
        if ((shmid = shmget(20441, sizeof(file_entry) + 256, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) {
            printf("shmget");
            exit(2);
        }

        entries = (file_entry*) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        if (entries == NULL) {
            printf("problem2");
            exit(2);
        }

        printf("\nChild Reading ....\n\n");
        printf("%d\n", entries->pid);
        printf("%s\n", entries->tipo);
        printf("%s\n", entries->nome);
        printf("%lu\n", entries->genoma);
        putchar('\n');
        printf("\nDone\n\n");
    } else {
        if ((shmid = shmget(20441, sizeof(file_entry) + 256, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) {
            printf("problem3");
            exit(2);
        }

        entries = (file_entry *) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        if (entries == NULL ) {
            printf("problem4");
            exit(2);
        }
        printf("done attachment");

        int pidD = 4001;
        char tipoD[2] = "A";
        char nomeD[20] = "sfds";
        unsigned long genomaD = 10000;


        entries->pid  = pidD;
        sprintf(entries->tipo,"%s",tipoD);
        sprintf(entries->nome,"%s",nomeD);
        entries->genoma= genomaD;


        wait(NULL);
        shmdt(&shmid);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This `entries->tipo =tipoD;
    entries->nome =nomeD;` won't compile.

Comment: shared memory example 2.c:70:23: error: array type 'char [2]' is not assignable
        entries->tipo =tipoD;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
    shared memory example 2.c:71:23: error: array type 'char [20]' is not assignable
        entries->nome =nomeD;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^

Comment: I tried running your code but it still gives me the problem3 error, I guess that something with the size of the structure isnt allowing me to read it properly